# SQLj in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sqlj

I want to connect SQLj with Eclipse. I have done this steps: http://mojo.codehaus.org/sqlj-maven-plugin/usage.html

But when I want to compile SQLj files I receive an message

```
null (org.codehaus.mojo:sqlj-maven-plugin:1.3:sqlj:sqlj:generate-sources)
```

I have win7 64x and Java 7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's a compatibility issue,looks like sqlj versioning issue.Not sure since I do not have complete details.

Comment: What can I provide you? This is my pom.xml - http://pastebin.com/pzRKv0Tb ; To add SQLj translator I use file from Oracle "11.2.0\dbhome_2\sqlj\lib" folder. There I found translator.jar file

Comment: I have provided you the link http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/java.112/e10590/getstart.htm#i1007984,please make sure you have the proper sqlj environments. As I can see in the doc it supperts jdk 1.5 or 1.6.

Comment: When in maven I click generate-sources I have following errors: http://pastebin.com/mN1ALuTZ Lokesh, yes I have this library: http://i.imgur.com/P4yh2uV.png

Comment: Thank you for this link, I will check it tomorrow :)

Comment: I am not exactly sure, you may want to look at the documentation.May have missed something. JDK version should be 1.5 or 1.6!!!

Comment: Thank you, when I change JDK to 6 all is working good. But.. Where I should have translated sqlj files? Or.. How should I use sqlj?

Comment: As I mentioned in above comment about JDK requirement,I am glad it worked for you. I will provide you the link ,very similar to the connection pooling in jdbc. There is a simple example on page 2 as you can check.Follow the steps- http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/books/Oracle9-chapter-6.pdf. Please make sure you mark it as answer since other users may be looking for the same.

Answer (score 0):

Double check if you have JDK 1.7 (not just JRE) *Windows->Java->Installed JREs*: check JDK 1.7 and in *...Installed JREs->Execution Envirement* check that JavaSE-1.7 has as compatible JRE your JDK 1.7.

[image]